# Does 301 redirect refresh the url in the browser

Tags: asp.net, redirect

for SEO reasons we are issuing a 301 redirect from the code. Its working perfectly fine and i can see 301 moved in the firebug.

I searched in the net and couldn't get proper answer. Does 301 redirect refreshes the browser url also?

for example i am in

```
www.test.com/hello1
```

its moved to

```
www.test.com/hello2
```

i am seeing the contents from hello2 , but does the browser shows

www.test.com/hello2 or www.test.com/hello1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. It works like a normal redirect.

Comment: is it , but in my case i am not seeing the browser getting refreshed , but firebug shows 301

Comment: You mean the URL does not change in the address bar? What do other browsers do?

Comment: yes usr , the URL is not changing in the browser, let me test other browsers

Comment: i found , there is some space in the URL , it works now , thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

As stated at [seomoz](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/url-rewrites-and-301-redirects-how-does-it-all-work):

> Rewriting a URL means changing the way the URL is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Rewriting is different from redirecting. This answer does not answer the question.